# How to avoid KeyUp event to spread to parent control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, keyup

Let's say I have 3 WinForms

Form C contained in Form B contained in Form A

In Form C and Form B, I want to trap the KeyUp event so that I can close the form upon pressing "Escape". Just like this:

```
Private Sub formB_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
     Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Escape
           Me.Close()
     End Select
End Sub
```

The problem is, when I press "Escape" in Form C, it also triggers the KeyUp from Form B, thus closing both Forms.  Form C looks like this, I had to override the ProcessCmdKey so it could work on that form also.

```
Private Sub formC_KeyUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
     Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Escape
           Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
           Me.Close()
           e.SuppressKeyPress = True
     End Select
End Sub

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keydata As Keys) As Boolean
     If keydata = Keys.Escape Then
        OnKeyUp(New KeyEventArgs(keydata))
        ProcessCmdKey = True
     Else
        ProcessCmdKey = MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keydata)
     End If
End Function
```

I know I could simply put the  Me.KeyPreview = False in Form B, but doing this would prevent the Escape Key from being used to escape Form B.

Comment: "Handles Me.KeyUp" is rather strange, not sure what you are doing.  Make sure you let the designer generate event handlers for you.  Using the form's KeyUp event is almost never correct, it will not work when the form has any child controls.  Using ProcessCmdKey() is the correct way, but just call Me.Close(), calling OnKeyUp() is not correct.

Comment: if this is a Dialog (`Me.DialogResult = ...`) add a "Close" button for those expecting it, set the form's Cancel button to that.  Now when they press Escape its the same as pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the *KeyPreview* property to *true* in both `FormB and FormC` you can get the *Escape* key:

```
Private Sub FormC_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Escape) Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

The same with *FormB*